# cannot use ng2-pagination with angular2-webpack-starter

Tags: angular, pagination, webpack

I am using latest [ng2-pagination](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ng2-pagination) (0.4.1) and [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/package.json) (5.0.5).

My goal is to try `ng2-pagination`.

I followed the following steps:

- installed `ng2-pagination` using `npm install ng2-pagination --save;`
- added `import 'ng2-pagination'` to `vendor.browser.ts`;
- added `import {Ng2PaginationModule} from 'ng2-pagination';` to `app.module.ts`, then added `Ng2PaginationModule` to its imports array;
- altered `detail.component.ts` like so:

  ```
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';
  @Component({
  selector: 'detail',
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from Detail</h1>
    <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of collection | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p }">{{ item }}</li>
    </ul>
    <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event" #api>
    </pagination-controls>`
  })
  export class Detail {
  collection = [];
  constructor() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      this.collection.push(`item ${i}`);
      }
    }
  }
  ```

---

I get the following error:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'paginate' could not be found
```

> It seems to me that the component doesn't know about ng2-paginate: what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I fixed it:

The blunder was in the third step; instead of:

- `import {Ng2PaginationModule} from 'ng2-pagination';` to `app.module.ts`, then add `Ng2PaginationModule` to its imports array;

I should have done the following:

- `import {Ng2PaginationModule} from 'ng2-pagination';` to **`./+detail/index.ts`**, then add `Ng2PaginationModule` to its imports array;

Guess I wasn't familiar enough with latest angular2. Hope this will help someone.